# Unable to find groovy class from a Java class

Tags: java, groovy

I'm using Eclipse IDE. I have a groovy class called B.groovy

```
Class B
{  
// some groovy code here  
}
```

Now I have a Java class called A.java  & I need to call a groovy method from this class A but I keep getting a compilation error. I have the groovy-all-1.7.5 jar file in my build path but still I get the compilation problem. Both these classes are part of the same package. What am I missing here? How do I resolve this compilation error ?

```
public class A{  
B.method()  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your build path is inconsistent.  Your groovy .class files need to be in the same build directory as your javac will emit.  Adding a -cp groovy/build to point to where groovyc generated its .class files should resolve your problem.

Hm, clarification:

```
groovyc myGroovy.groovy
javac -cp groovy/build myJava.java
```

If you used [this tutorial](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Create+Your+First+Groovy+Project) then you probably have different projects.  In that case, just add to the Java project dependencies your Groovy project and it will resolve the groovy class files for you.  This is under Project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Projects -> Add ... and pick your Groovy project.

Comment: How do I fix that in eclipse? Is a build directory the bin folder? I do see B.groovy and A.class in that folder ..

Comment: Yes, Eclipse defaults to using the "bin/" as the output directory for java.  If you don't see B.class in that directory, the groovyc is configured differently or not building.  It would help if you added details to your question with your project directory structure and plugins.